# Configuring Neo4j v2.2.3 with Eclipse or other Java platform

Tags: eclipse, neo4j

Could someone please advise me on how to connect Neo4j version 2.2.3 with Eclipse, or recommend another Java platform and how to connect Neo4j.

I am able to execute queries independently on neo4j and eclipse but I am not able to connect both to realise graph representation.

Answer (score 2):

You have few options here, if your goal is to communicate with Neo4j thru Eclipse as a client.

- Use neoclipse for connection to Neo4j from Eclipse

  - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse
- Use Neo4j JDBC connector

  - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc

If you goal is to connect from your java application to Neo4j you have lot more options.

- If your application is Spring application you can use SDN

  - http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/4.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/
- OGM project

  - https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm
- REST API

  - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html

Could you please tell us more about your goal?